# is the both dua authentic or one of them is authentic?

Tags: source-identification, dua, sahih-bukhari

### Dua 1

is

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6369

حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ بْنُ مَخْلَدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا سُلَيْمَانُ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عَمْرُو بْنُ أَبِي عَمْرٍو، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَنَسًا، قَالَ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنَ الْهَمِّ **وَالْحَزَنِ**، وَالْعَجْزِ وَالْكَسَلِ، وَالْجُبْنِ وَالْبُخْلِ، وَضَلَعِ الدَّيْنِ، وَغَلَبَةِ الرِّجَالِ ‏"‏‏.‏

Narrated Anas bin Malik: The Prophet (ﷺ) used to say, "O Allah! I seek refuge with You from worry and grief, from incapacity and laziness, from cowardice and miserliness, from being heavily in debt and from being overpowered by (other) men." (See Hadith No. 374)

### Dua 2

https://sunnah.com/hisn:121
or
https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2458

Anas said that the Prophet used to say, “O God, I seek refuge in Thee from care, grief, incapacity, slackness, cowardliness, niggardliness, the burden of debt, and being overpowered by men.”

وَعَنْ أَنَسٍ قَالَ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ يَقُولُ: «اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنَ الْهَمِّ **وَالْحُزْنِ** وَالْعَجْزِ وَالْكَسَلِ وَالْجُبْنِ وَالْبُخْلِ وَضَلَعِ الدَّيْنِ وَغَلَبَةِ الرِّجَالِ»

---

Both is almost same but the difference is one of them has **وَالْحَزَنِ** and other has **وَالْحُزْنِ** is there any big difference in meaning?

So the reason for asking is that one of them has a been graded authentic that is dua 1
But i couldn't find any grading of dua 2. **Can any one tell me if dua 2 is sahih?**

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no big difference in meaning between "وَالْحَزَنِ" and "وَالْحُزْنِ".

And the second Dua is also Sahih:

> I used to often hear the Prophet () supplicating with these words: ‘O
> Allah, I seek refuge in You from sadness, grief, helplessness,
> laziness, being stingy, overwhelming debt, and the overpowering of men.
>
> ~ [Al-Tirmidi 3484](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3484)